# I'ma victim of a theft my Chromebook was stolen a couple years ago with ethereum and some other coins in my metamask account can I regain access

Tags: metamask, etherscan, cpp-ethereum

I was unfortunately a victim of theft. My Chromebook was stolen w/my metamask acct. It had ETH I purchased from matrixport & 700,000 Like Coins also. Is it anyway I can get access to it? Note that I do have the etherscan account that I had my contract and my ethereum from the metamask account with I still have access to that. It's been over 2 years or write it two years since my Chromebook was stolen.
Thank you...

Comment: If you have the seed phrase you can recover them. Always remember to backup it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the unfortunate incident. Have you tried recovering your eth/maatamask account? This can only be possible if you remember or have the seedphrase/private key saved.